# Android to Drupal user creation

Tags: android, drupal, profile

For anyone who might need help creating a Drupal user from an Android app, the following code works:

```
    //create a new HttpClient and post header
    HttpClient httpClient   =   new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost       =   new HttpPost("http://test.site.com/testpoint/user/register");

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try{
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs  =   new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add( new BasicNameValuePair("account[pass]", "cutelady"));
    nameValuePairs.add( new BasicNameValuePair("account[mail]", "scarter@sgc.gov"));
    nameValuePairs.add( new BasicNameValuePair("account[name]", "Samantha Carter"));
    httpPost.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    
    //Execute HTTP post request
    HttpResponse response   =   httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("HTTP ERROR", e.toString());
}
```

However, I have an additional problem: when using the profile module to provide additional custom CCK fields for the user registration process, I can't find the right `account[cck_parameter]` to connect and save my Android data to the profile CCK field.

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

User is a user object and extra profile values are node objects. So the user_save function is designed to accept few params.
The key is, you can create user profiles overriding "required field" status of the user/register form. 
Keep the current form, and try to create a new node too, after saving the user object.

See content profile API to see how to save(it's a node_save() ) a content profile.